# How to set a nested properties value on a FacebookAds::AdSet object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-business-sdk

I am currently using the [facebook-ruby-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk) to manage ads on Facebook.

I have written a method to update a `FacebookAds::AdSet` object.

```
# Fetch the adset
adset = FacebookAds::AdSet.get(source_adset_id, session)

# Set the new name
adset.name = 'Test name'

# Save the Adset
adset.save
```

That works and sets the name, but if i try to set a nested property like so:

```
adset = FacebookAds::AdSet.get(source_adset_id, session)

# Set the new minimum age 
adset.targeting.age_min = 20

# this is the adset's new min age (should be 20)
p adset.age_min
#=> 18

# Save the Adset
adset.save
```

When i set the `adset.targeting.age_min` the value is never set, this goes for any nested value that i try to set.

Am i setting this value the wrong way? Is there any other way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess their gem does not allow to update the child's attributes.

My workaround was creating a targeting hash like so:

```
targeting = {
    age_min: 20
}
```

Once you have your hash created, just set it to the object like so:

```
adset.targeting = targeting
```

And finally:

```
adset.save
```